# coreutils: print nth line in file, block until it exists

Tags: linux, shell, gnu-coreutils

How would I print the nth line of a file or input, and block until it exists?  I want to stick to coreutils.

`sed 'NUMq;d' file` will quickly give me the nth line, but doesn't block.

`tail -f file` will block, but doesn't do the other thing.

I should be able to pipe the line to something else eg with a file:

`<block-until-line-20-exists> file | <process-line>`

or, with input:

`tail -n 0 -f file | <block-until-line-20-exists> | <process-line>`

Comment: Re: `tail -n 0 -f file | block-until-line-20-exists`, think about `{ while (( i=0; i<20; i++)); do IFS= read -r line; done; printf '%s\n' "$line"; }` as something that could fill in `block-until-line-20-exists`. Assuming your shell is actually bash; for /bin/sh the loop will be uglier.

Comment: ...on which point: _Do_ you need POSIX sh compatibility here, or can a shell with ksh extensions (as adopted by both bash and zsh) be assumed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind.  I think I answered my own question.  `tail` & `sed` is the solution after all.

`tail -n 0 -f file | sed '20q;d'`

Turns out that `tail` stops blocking after `sed` completes.

EDIT: depending on how you use this, there is a potential for a time-of-check/time-of-use bug.